# Changing global IPv6 address vs. docker using fixed-cidr-v6

Tags: docker, ipv6

To enable IPv6 in my docker setup, I've set this in the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
"ipv6": true,
"fixed-cidr-v6": "2a01:xxxx:yyyy:zzzz/64"
}
```

I got the `2a01:xxxx:yyyy:zzzz` from my ISP and found it via `ip addr | grep inet6 | grep global`.

My ISP keeps changing the `zzzz` bit, and it also changes when restarting the router.

Questions:

- A) Is there a docker setup that does not require hardcoding changing values? (Idea: Setting `fixed-cidr-v6` to some link-local value `fd00:...`)
- B) I can use a dynamic dns client to update my domains AAAA record. But again the IPv6 is hardcoded in my local setup.
- C) Docker seems not usable with IPv6 in the real world. Do I have to run my apps directly on the host (not in containers) behind a reverse proxy?

Comment: Don't run servers at home.

Comment: Know that, heard that before. Still doesn't help. I have my local development server at home with a macmini for license reasons. It is not critical for customer experience, collocation is overkill, and renting macs in the cloud is too expensive.

Comment: Maybe VPN is the solution for some problems. Have not tried that with IPv6 yet. Anyway the webhooks to the buildserver would not work with VPN.

Comment: You should have a chat with your ISP and ask them to kindly stop changing your IPv6 prefix. This is unfortunately common in some European countries where ISPs do this for "privacy" reasons. For those of us who have work to do, it's a horrible inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot get a static IPv6, then it's going to be difficult if you want to assign your Docker containers globally scoped (public) IPv6 Addresses. I've written a guide on using [public IPv6 addresses in Docker](https://battlepenguin.com/tech/bee2-in-production-ipv6-haproxy-and-docker/), but it does rely on static IPv6 addresses (often available on Virtual Machines in hosted environments).

The alternative is using the [Docker IPv6Nat Daemon](https://github.com/robbertkl/docker-ipv6nat)

I prefer this technique because it makes the IPv4 and IPv6 stacks consistent within Docker. I've written another [tutorial on fully isolating ingress and egress networks for Docker with IPv4 and IPv6 support](https://battlepenguin.com/tech/docker-with-ipv6-and-network-isolation/)